# How To Run a python script from Ruby/Cucumber-Calabash

Tags: android, python, cucumber, calabash, androidviewclient

I have a problem with Calabash/Cucumber, i need to launch a python script, generated by culebra (androidviewclient) that in a few words, click on an external view to my application. 
This is my ruby page class:

```
require 'calabash-android/abase'    
class SignUpPage < Calabash::ABase

def login_google_confirm_step_1
    system '/PATH/social_login_step_1.py'
end
```

And this is my step:

```
Then(/^I am able to submit google login step 1$/) do
@current_page = page(SignUpPage)
@current_page.login_google_confirm_step_1
end
```

When i lunch the cucumber features i have this error:

```
UiTests/features/android/pages/signup_page.rb
Failed to load 'py' programming language for file UiTests/features/android/pages/social_login_step_1.py: cannot load such file -- rubypython
* UiTests/features/android/pages/social_login_step_1.py [NOT SUPPORTED]
```

I have already install rubypython gem,and I can not find any topic on the net that can help me. 
Someone could help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved.... the problem was the path where i saved the python-script (social_login_step_1.py), i removed the file from pages/ directory, where the contents were various pages.rb and running again all